# Autocomplete display all data from database ( Not according to words type in input field )

Tags: javascript, php, html, codeigniter

**ERROR**

Dropdown used for input field in view displays all data from the database. But not accroding to the word typed by users.

For Example:

If database `product` consists of different `product_name` such as Pepsi, Slice and Coke.

**Problem** = When the user types anyvalue in input field it fetches all data from database such as Pepsi, Slice and Coke.

**Solution Wanted** = Input field must display accrording to word typed by user, if they will enter letter k then it must display Coke. As `product_name` Coke only consists letter k ion it.

**VIEW**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){
          $("#get_names_product").autocomplete({
            source: "<?php echo site_url('inventory/get_product_names'); ?>" // path to the get_product_name method
          });
        });
    </script>

<form name="frmOne" id="newBatch" class="form-horizontal" action="" method="post">

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="customerName" style="color:#3fa9f5;" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Product Name</label>
             <div class="col-sm-8">
                    <input type="text" value="<?php echo isset($post)?$post->product_name:''; ?>" class="form-control" name="systemProduct[product_name]" id="get_names_product" placeholder="Enter Product Name">
             </div>
     </div>
</form>
```

**Controller**

```
function get_product_names()
{
    $this->load->model('productModel', 'product');
    if (isset($_GET['term'])) {
        $q = strtolower($_GET['term']);
        $this->product->get_name_product($q);
    }
}
```

**Model**

```
function get_name_product($q)
{
    $q = $this->db->query("SELECT distinct `product_name` FROM `product` where `deleteProduct` = '0' ");
    if ($q->num_rows() > 0) {
        foreach ($q->result_array() as $row) {
            $row_set[] = htmlentities(stripslashes($row['product_name'])); //build an array
        }
        echo json_encode($row_set); //format the array into json data
    }
}
```

Comment: your query must be something like " SELECT distinct `product_name` FROM `product` where `deleteProduct` = '0'  AND  product_name LIKE '".$searchword."%'";

Comment: It does not fetch anything from database if i use that @shubham

Comment: run this query directly in your database and tell me if you face any error.and please change query according to your db fields.

Comment: @subham the query does not display any error.

Comment: SELECT distinct `product_name` FROM `product` where `deleteProduct` = '0' and product_name LIKE '%$q%' 
worked for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the LIKE keyword in your select query.

```
select product_name from product where deleteProduct = '0' AND productName LIKE "%'.$q.'%"
```

Comment: Now it does not display anything .. @PHPGeek